# How to move images from one div to another when checkbox is checked javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, checkbox

I was wondering how to move images from one div to another when checkbox is checked, using JavaScript. They all should be in div class="ekran" when checkbox is checked, but in the same time if you check another checkbox, the previous one is unchecked and the previous image should disappear. I have been trying to figure this one out but I can't seem to find any solution. SO, if you have some ideas...

```js
window.addEventListener('load', start, false);


function start() {
    
    var slike = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var ekran = document.getElementsByClassName('ekran')[0];
    document.body.addEventListener('click', menjaj, false);

    function menjaj(e) {
         var img = document.createElement('img'); 
         img.src = slike.src;
         ekran.innerHTML = ''; 
         ekran.appendChild(img);   

    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="omotac">
    <div>

          <label><input type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto1.jpg" alt="leto1"></label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto2.jpg" alt="leto2"></label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto3.jpg" alt="leto3"></label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto4.jpg" alt="leto4"></label>
         
         
    </div>
    
    <div class="ekran"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is something not clear about your question, based on the code you provided here it doesn't work with the structure you could be looking for, would you please be more specific about what you want to do? do you want to move one image at a time or every selected image? try to explain more please..

Comment: i am trying to move only one image at a time when checkbox above that image is selected, and i want to move them to div class="ekran", so if one checkbox is selected image that is below that goes to div ekran, also if i check some other checkbox the new image should be in div ekran. I know i should probably to this with radio buttons, but i want the checkbox. @Kai

Answer (score -1):

You can use append the inner html by setting a target for the div you want the image to be copied to.

This is the line that does it

```
target.innerHTML += document.getElementById(checked).parentElement.innerHTML
```

Here is a working version from your code.

```js
function myFunction(checked) {
console.log ("checked is ", checked)
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(checked);
  var target = document.getElementById('target')
  // If the checkbox is checked, move the image
  if (checkBox.checked == true){

  
  target.innerHTML += document.getElementById(checked).parentElement.innerHTML
    //remove one line below if you do not want to hide div from source
  checkBox.parentElement.innerHTML='';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="source" class="omotac">
    <div>

          <label><input id="c1" onclick=myFunction("c1")   type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto1.jpg" alt="leto1"></label>
          <label><input id="c2" onclick=myFunction("c2")  type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto2.jpg" alt="leto2"></label>
          <label><input id="c3" onclick=myFunction("c3")  type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto3.jpg" alt="leto3"></label>
          <label><input id="c4" onclick=myFunction("c4")  type="checkbox" name="odabir"><img src="slike/leto4.jpg" alt="leto4"></label>
         
         
    </div>
    
    <div class="ekran">
    <h1>This is target div </h1>
    <div id="target"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Alex If this solved your question, please consider accepting as an answer.